# Raid array degraded after reboot

Tags: hard-drive, raid, reboot, mdadm

I do not know if cross-posting is allowed, but i waited 2 weeks and sadly got now answer or could solve my problem by myself.

In Short: Everytime I have to re-boot our PC the RAID-6 array consisting of 6 identical HDD's fails and I have to manually add the drive (everytime the same one /dev/sde or the 5th out of 6) to re-assremble the array, which takes time and is mega-annoying. I found the logs and can provide them if necessary.

Original Thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645840/missing-drive-in-software-raid-array-after-reboot

"Faulty drive test"

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 242) Self-test routine in progress...
                                        20% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   93) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (1183) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0004   130   130   054    Old_age   Offline      -       108
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   197   197   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       269 (Average 399)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   100   100   067    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0004   128   128   020    Old_age   Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6677
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   060    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
 22 Helium_Level            0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       322
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       322
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   180   180   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 19/42)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6537         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6369         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6201         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6036         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5865         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5698         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5563         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5399         -
# 9  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5227         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5059         -
#11  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4891         -
#12  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4733         -
#13  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4555         -
#14  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4387         -
#15  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4219         -
#16  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4051         -
#17  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3887         -
#18  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3715         -
#19  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3547         -
#20  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3379         -
#21  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3214         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you sure that the problem disk is in good health?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All drives have the same age and are about 6M old and nobody disassembled the PC/changed hardware during that time. Do you think that it might be the cause of my problems? that I may received a faulty unit.

Comment: Everything is possible. If you're on Windows then check the Event Viewer for errors. Check the SMART info of the disks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll and edit this post after the RAID has recovered

Comment: So i added the smart info of the "bad drive"

Comment: The drive seems in perfect health. Try to follow [this post](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO-6.html) so as to better analyze the error. Post error messages that seem pertinent.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I added more info. If I run "grep -rni "md0" * in /var/log I just get the above logs (and some otherones, wich do not seem relevant). Seems as mdadm cannot activate sde, but I dont know :(